# Make changes to a common template for various projects through git and have those changes reflected in the projects

Tags: git

At work we have decided to create a common template for the multiple projects we are carrying out, so that we have the same basis on which to work and give a solid corporate image. This template consists of a frontend project and a backend project with the common parts already implemented, such as migrations of the common entities in the database, their models, calls to APIs, the common part of the frontend, etc.

The idea is that each group works on its own project, but that if any changes are made to the common template, we can all see that change reflected in our projects without having to manually add the changes.

Since the implementation is going to continue in the same framework files, I don't think git submodules will solve my problem. Is there a way to do this with git or some other tool?

**Edit:** We are using Angular and contemplating whether to use Laravel or Symfony.

Comment: I don't think git is the right tool for this kind of actions. Especially if you need the template to update on already implemented solutions by updating the template.

You didn't specify what language or framework you are using. Maybe you should use the possibilities they provide.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will try to look outside git. Adding the frameworks to the question.